# Get line by line execution time .Net profiler

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, profiler, rider, dottrace

I set up a unit test to see how a method is performing,

 then I ran the method with dotTrace profiler trying different modes.

 It gives me a very detailed report but I can't find anywhere the execution time of each line of code within the method.

Is it possible to see how long it took each line of a method took to execute in a .Net application with dotTrace or the visual studio profiler?

[PerfTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/perftips?view=vs-2022) from visual studio gives me this information, but requires to debug line by line manually and there is no report functionality.

Comment: It is not good idea to use Visual Studio Profiler to get execution time line by line. Because the Visual Studio Profiler collect performance data without debugging. You can use the Visual Studio Profiler to get the usage time of each method in your program.

Comment: What people usually want to do is reduce execution time, which means finding the lines that use a lot of time, not a little. That's what [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) does.